# EF Core update navigation property but FK hidden property not update

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

```
public class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public NpgsqlTsVector SearchVector { get; set; }

    /**
    Navigation Property
     */

    public Location ParentLocation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Children")]
    public virtual ICollection<Location> ChildrenLocation { get; set; }

}
```

this self referencing entity class generate field "ParentLocationId" in the database (Hidden key).

Add when I use the following code to update..

```
    public async Task<Location> UpdateLocation(Location location, int? moveToParentLocation)
    {
        // this work
        // _context.Entry(location).Property("ParentLocationId").CurrentValue = moveToParentLocation;

        // this not work
        _context.Entry(location).Reference(loc => loc.ParentLocation).CurrentValue = null;

        _context.Locations.Update(location);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return location;
    }
```

`Reference()` doesn't work, and because I don't want to hardcode database field with `Property()` what did I do wrong.

PS. Location sent to this method is not attached to `DBContext` yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design of your method requires setting the shadow FK property. If you don't want to hardcode the name, you could use the [NavigationEntry.Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.navigationentry.metadata?view=efcore-2.1) property to find the FK property name and use it for `Property` method.

Something like this:

```
var entry = _context.Update(location);

var parentLocationProperty = entry.Property(
    entry.Reference(loc => loc.ParentLocation).Metadata.ForeignKey.Properties[0].Name
);
parentLocationProperty.CurrentValue = moveToParentLocation;

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```